# How does one evaluate $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(i+1)x^{-i}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  {(n+2)}x^{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123023/how-to-calculate-sum-n-0-infty-n2xn)

I'm sorry if I'm asking in wrong title .. I'm not a math expert ...

I need to know the rule behind this problem & how did it ended like this :)

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)x^{-i} = \frac{1}{(1-x^{-1})^2}$$

I'm ready to clarify any question you need to ask .

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120091/how-do-we-get-the-result-of-the-summation-sum-limits-k-1n-k-cdot-2k/120100#120100 and see if it helps.  The same technique will apply to your term in $ix^{-i}$  Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123023/how-to-calculate-sum-n-0-infty-n2xn

Comment: And see [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122175/inverse-of-1-ts-in-the-power-series-ring/122177#122177)

Comment: So why we integrate ? & how you guys search by equation & find similar problems here ?

Comment: Sorry , I mean differentiate

Comment: I found the other questions because I had answered one in the past and seen the other recently.  If you click on your name at the top of the page you can see all your activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=x^{-1}$ (Thanks, Mark):

$$S=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(i+1)y^i=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}iy^i+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}y^i$$
$$u=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}iy^i=0+y+2y^2+\dots$$
$$u-yu=0+y+2y^2+\dots-(0+y^2+2y^3+\dots)=y+y^2+\dots $$
$$y+y^2+\dots=z$$
$$z-yz=y+y^2+\dots-(y^2+y^3+\dots)=y$$
$$z=\frac{y}{1-y}$$
$$u-yu=\frac{y}{1-y} \Rightarrow u=\frac{y}{(1-y)^2}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}y^i=1+z$$
$$\therefore S=1+\frac{y}{1-y}+\frac{y}{(1-y)^2}=\frac{(1-y)^2+y(1-y)+y}{(1-y)^2}=\frac{(1-y)^2+y(2-y)}{(1-y)^2}=\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you put $y=x^{-1}$ then you are summing $1+2y+3y^2+...$

Then you could try summing $1+y+y^2+y^3+...$ and differentiating both sides.

You will have to do a little work to verify convergence, if that is a significant consideration for you.

Comment: Is there a name for a theory or something ? I really didn't get it :)

Comment: @xsari3x did you notice that $d/dy(1+y+y^2+y^3+\dots)=1+2y+3y^2+\dots$ ?

Comment: @M.Alaggan Yes , but ....Aha I deffe the Summation of the first one  , to get the 2nd one

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is as follows: $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty(i+1)x^{-i}=1+2x^{-1}+3x^{-2}+\ldots$$ $$=(1+x^{-1}+x^{-2}+\ldots)+(x^{-1}+x^{-2}+\ldots)+(x^{-2}+\ldots)$$ $$=(1+x^{-1}+x^{-2}+\ldots)(1+x^{-1}+x^{-2}+\ldots)=\frac{1}{(1-x^{-1})^2}$$

Comment: It might be clearer if you added steps between the last two lines: $= 1/(1-1/x) + x^{-1}/(1-1/x) + x^{-2}/(1-1/x)$... $=(1+1/x+1/x^2+...)/(1-1/x)$.

Comment: No harm meant in saying this, but "simple" is purely opinion. There can be elegance in simplicity, but mathematics, like life, is not always elegant and rarely simple.

Comment: By simplest I meant two things: a) This method does not require any additional advanced methods such as differentiating series (see * below); b) It is one of the best method to quickly get the answer for such series even without pen and paper(compare to any other you have seen). * That being said, I must add that it also requires one to check whether you can rearrange the terms in the sum. Likely, in our case this thing converges iff it converges absolutely: for $|x|>1$. I do not think any other solution, including differentiating, even mentions the conditions under which it works.